# how to emulate parallel multi-user usability testing with django and selenium/grid?

Tags: django, testing, selenium, selenium-grid

I can get my Selenium tests running fine for one user/ sequentially on Django 1.4 using [LiveServerTestCase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#django.test.LiveServerTestCase), but I would like to emulate parallel multi-user testing.  I don't think I need real load testing, since my apps are mostly moderate/low traffic web-sites and internal web-apps, so I would prefer to avoid extra tools like JMeter.

I've started out setting up [Selenium Grid](http://selenium-grid.seleniumhq.org/) but am not sure how to keep my tests independent and still run multiple tests with multiple users.  I assume the test cases should be run for different users on the same DB simultaneously - but each test drops and creates a new DB, so I don't understand how that is possible.

And I don't want to sign up for a service like [BrowserMob](http://browsermob.com).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a tool like JMeter anyways for a couple different reasons:

1. If you want to test that there are no bugs when multiple users are hitting the service at the same time, you won't be guaranteed that will happen running two or more automated selenium tests at the same time since it can take quite a while to perform whatever actions happen before a request is actually sent to the server.  You are much more likely to hit these kinds of bugs when using a tool like jmeter that can send multiple requests simultaneously with little to no lag between requests.  You also can easily execute a lot more threads of jmeter at the same time than you can of Selenium.
2. If you actually want to test the performance of your site, or the behavior of your site while under more than normal load, you can more easily do this with tools like jmeter.

With that said, if you really want to use Selenium for this, I know that it is fairly simple with Selenium2/Webdriver, however I am not familiar enough with Selenium Grid to provide guidance on what would be required there.

Comment: I'm using Selenium2/Webdriver but can't figure out how to use it for multiple users on the same database.  I thought that was what Selenium Grid was for, but I can't figure that out either.  If this is simple, do you know of any sample code or tutorials - esp. with Django 1.4 as I would like to leverage the new Selenium/ LiveServerTestCase integration.

Comment: I haven't used Selenium Grid, but you can use something like nunit or anything else to spawn multiple processes of Selenium/Webdriver that run in parallel.

Comment: Fyi, it seems like I can get pretty reliable simultaneous requests going at the same time.  I tried this with 10 selenium tests, and was able to view overlapping user behavior in the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured this out but welcome more (potentially more elegant) solutions.

I'm running both "clean" and "dirty" tests.  The "clean" tests are just normal Selenium tests that set up and tear down the DB after every test.  The "dirty" tests are run by passing options to my subclassed DjangoTestSuiteRunner which tell it whether or not to set up or tear down the DB, and also pass in a user id, like so:

```
python manage.py test myapp --testrunner=testrunner.MySeleniumTestRunner \ 
    --no_setup_db --no_teardown_db --user=1234 --liveserver=localhost:8081
```

I then string together about 10 of these commands in a shell script and log the output.

The only tricky part is writing your tests in a way that take into account both kinds of test.  So, for example, if I'm testing simply adding a product to a shopping cart in my clean test and checking for the item in the cart to indicate success, then I also need to add a condition that checks for things like product availability.  So when I run my dirty tests, if there are only four products available, then the first four users are successful because the product was available and I verified the product was added to their cart - but the fifth user *also* passes the test, because when the product is not available I check for proper error handling, etc.

I know this isn't very unit-test like, and may be even rather non-standard for functional testing, but I think it emulates parallel multi-user testing pretty well, without compromising test independence.