# How to run test in parallel using Selenium(LiveServerTestCase) in django project?

Tags: django, testing, selenium, parallel-processing

here is the problem:

I have a class which is inherited from LiveServerTestCase. This class imitate some users(client) work - go to the site, filling some fields, add files. 
I need to imitate multi users work so I need to run this class(function) in parallel.

Is there any ways to do that, just using standard python's things like threads, processes and Selenium-2? If not, please write some simple example of your suggestion.

Thanks!

Comment: you can add to your question whatever you tried and didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I usually distinguish functional (system) django tests and performance/load/multi-user tests based on tools like [multi-mechanize](http://testutils.org/multi-mechanize/) or [locust](http://locust.io/).

Here's what you can try though.

[Nose](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) can run your tests in [parallel](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/doc_tests/test_multiprocess/multiprocess.html) (see also [django_nose](https://github.com/jbalogh/django-nose)). But, you may have several problems with this:

- as far as every `LiveServerTestCase` opens up a browser on `localhost:port`, you should give it a list of ports to use in order to avoid `This port is already in use` errors:

  ```
  ./manage.py test --liveserver=localhost:8082,8090-8100,9000-9200,7041
  ```
- probably, creating and truncating database tables by your `LiveServerTestCases` will cause your tests to fail (the behavior can be changed though)

Also see:

- [how to emulate parallel multi-user usability testing with django and selenium/grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290294/how-to-emulate-parallel-multi-user-usability-testing-with-django-and-selenium-gr?rq=1)